# Is it haram to sell Luxury items?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, business, social-media

I own a instagram page in the luxury niche. I run this page to sell luxury items (like watches & etc.). I know islam doesn’t encourage you to live a luxurious life or waste money on worldly things, rather donate and help the poor! I really don't want my business/income to be haram. I don't post any haram content on my page (i.e. music, women,  nudity). I usually would be posting pictures & videos of cars,watches etc. Will i be sinful to run a business like this?

Please answer wisely! May Allah Bless You & keep your family healthy & safe <3

Comment: What do you mean by '<3'? I find that puzzling.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah `<3` is a typographical representation of a heart, used to convey love and similar warm feelings online and often evoking early internet culture.

Answer (score 1):

**Praise be to Allah.**

If material does not follow non Islamic culture (like doll), It's halal.

But There are some materials people can use those  for good or  bad work both. Like Radio and Knife,

Some radio channel telecast  Quran recitation , Adhan , Islamic conversation  etc,

And anyone can use knife for home work and bad people use it to kill people.

**In Quran**

Allah will not hold you accountable for unintentional oaths, but for what you intended in your hearts. And Allah is All-Forgiving, Most Forbearing.

[al-Baqarah 2:225]

if anyone  sell those (like radio, knife), never sold it to bad people or criminal.. if anyone do it, he/she  will accountable on  the judgment day

**Below Some Hdith about Beautification**

Muslim in his Saheeh, no. 131, from ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood, who narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “No one will enter Paradise who has an atom’s-weight of pride in his heart.” A man said, “What if a man likes his clothes to look good and his shoes to look good?” He said, “Allaah is beautiful and loves beauty. Pride means denying the truth and looking down on people.”

Ibn al-Qayyim (may Allaah have mercy on him) said, commenting on this hadeeth: the phrase “Allaah is beautiful and loves beauty” includes the beautiful clothing which was asked about in the same hadeeth. It is included by way of generalization, i.e., that beauty in all things is what is meant here. In Saheeh Muslim no. 1686 it says: “Allaah is good and only accepts that which is good.” In Sunan al-Tirmidhi it says: “Allaah loves to see the effects of His blessing on His slave.”

“O Children of Adam! We have bestowed raiment upon you to cover yourselves (screen your private parts, etc.) and as an adornment, and the raiment of righteousness, that is better.”
[al-A’raaf 7:26]

“And how many a generation have We destroyed before them. Who were better in wealth, goods and outward appearance?” [Maryam 19:54]

In Saheeh Muslim it is reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Allaah does not look at your outward appearance and your wealth, rather He looks at your hearts and deeds.”

Answer (score 0):

**Business** is not haram in islam.Yes it would be haram if you are selling haram thing like drugs, alcohol, women, and any other things that are haram in islam.

But so far I haven't read any hadith that prohibited the luxury item as long as it is halal, and watch , cloths, faniture etc are halal etc.

Even Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) was a merchant(i.e.Businessman)

Answer (score 0):

Gold is a luxurious product isn't it? It's just far more common. Its price is much higher than Silver. Silver gets the job done, but people want Gold. I'm pretty sure the Prophet bought gold (or luxurious items) for his wives and his daughter Hazrat Fatima.

You're doing the same. I don't think it's haram at all.

What's incorrect is to be obsessed with luxury. To use it to show off. To be too much attached to a antic and not sell it while your brother in deen needs money for surgery.

Comment: Surely you mean gold is less common, rather than 'far more common'? There is a hadith in Bukhari where the Prophet is known to throw away a gold ring because he saw others imitating him in wearing one.

Comment: No it’s correct. Gold is fat more common than luxury items. Like our mothers, grandmothers, sisters, wives and daughters usually have some gold. So it’s common. Far more commom than people having antic luxury items

Answer (score 0):

It depends that how much did you expanded your beliefs under Islam framework. buying luxury things mean being a part of culture that navigates capitals into 1% rich people. then it is not true.

Although that, you shouldn't be too obsessive or too worried about aligning everything with a pre-known or proofed thoughts or commands. take it easy, sometimes people need luxury things or gifts.

Combining these two guides, you shouldn't have a big luxury business according to Islam. And i think trying to sell less-expensive luxury things seem more ethical.

Answer (score 0):

Run your business. Earn profit. Spend on Zakat and other charities. Remember that your profits will not stay with you after death. Your deeds will.

There is nothing in Islam which forbids "hasanat" (good things) of this world. What is disastrous is forgetting that the next world is more important and enduring.