# Is it haram to make app like YouTube?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, taharah

I question is to develop a app like YouTube... It may contain haram as well as halal content... My primary goal is to not develop app like Amazon prime...where only entertainment and haram contents are available... But my goal is to develop a YouTube client that's it... It contains Islam contents; education contents, many useful things too... But it has entertainment too... Will I get punished when someone sees entertainment content from that client app.....

Comment: 'only entertainment and haram contents' --> typo perhaps? i think OP means halal not haram in this part idk

Answer (score 1):

If your app will "contain haram ... content", then in what way is it not haram?!?

Are you asking whether entertainment is haram? Not all of it is, some are.  People are allowed to be entertained. You will need to vet the content to ensure that it is halal.

Comment: it's not will but rather may. basically companies like youtube and facebook and stuff can't ensure everything will be wholesome content 100% of the time. they work 24/7 to remove the inappropriate stuff. i think this is what OP is saying. either this or that OP is saying some of the 'wholesome' stuff may be 'haram' in an islam-specific way (eg something non-muslims may consider ok but something muslims might not consider ok)...

Comment: also 'only entertainment and haram contents' --> typo perhaps? i think OP means halal not haram in this part idk

Comment: @BCLC: Facebook came onto moderation late and they pay them quite poorly and with little psychological support - given some of the stuff they have to read or watch.

Answer (score 0):

in your question scenario, You know this that it will contain entertainment(music & songs) content..

**In one word** It’s Haram

**If you think it this way, You will find  the answer**

*In general sense , if someone mix beer with water , will it be halal ?*

**In Quran**

And do not mix the truth with falsehood or conceal the truth while you know [it].
[Al-Baqara 2 : 42](https://qurano.com/en/2-al-baqara/verse-42)

Truth is the sign of good deeds and False is the sing of bad deeds ...

**You can read this verse also**

Allah does not impose blame upon you for what is unintentional in your oaths, but He imposes blame upon you for what your hearts have earned. And Allah is Forgiving and Forbearing.

[Al-Baqara 2 : 225](https://qurano.com/en/2-al-baqara/verse-225/)

Comment: But in one Islamic exchange stack , I find developing social media is not haram... YouTube is also a social media right ???

Comment: @Mohammed Hassan  but in your question scenario, You know this that  it will contain entertainment(music & songs) content.. also read this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65033/is-it-haram-to-sell-luxury-items/65043#65043)